# Ubuntu 12.04 lts heats laptop

Tags: overheating

My Toshiba Satellite L630-104 (Intel Core i3 M330 @2.13 GHz, 3GB RAM), overheats badly using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Am using Ubuntu in dual booting mode, heating doesn’t happen with window 7. Am new to Ubuntu & quite excited to use/learn but on couple of instance machine shut automatically due to overheat, it shoots up beyond 75C. After browsing for solution on internet, installed Jupiter/Gnome classis profile and now temperature ranges from 60 to 65. Is this healthy temperature, is there any other fix with which heating can be refused ?

Answer (score -1):

If there is a graphic card like nvidia, AMD in your laptop., goto that company site and download and install those drivers for linux !

This will works !

Comment: Not necessarily, because lack of GPU performance is just one possible problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But your answer is too broad and unspecific. Also, it's unclear if the overheating really stems from the graphics card.